# trigger.('click') not triggering the native click event on IE8

Tags: jquery, click

I have done the following code on a hidden field on IE8 :

```
 jQuery('#myfield').trigger('click')
```

But it's not working. On safari, I had the same problem, so I used :

```
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("click", true, true); 
document.getElementById('myfield').dispatchEvent(evt);
```

But this code is also not working on IE8.

Do you know what I could use on IE8?

Thanks in advance

Comment: which jquery version are you using?

Comment: What's the element you're trying to activate this way? BTW, `click` is a `MouseEvent`.

Comment: In IE 8, you can try [`fireEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536423(v=vs.85).aspx).  `document.getElementById('myfield').fireEvent('onclick');` (I think that's the right syntax).  `dispatchEvent` wasn't added until IE 9.

Comment: Why do you need the native event?

Comment: "the following code on a hidden field" You mean input type hidden???

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Also, try  jQuery('#myfield').click;

Comment: @JanL without a `()` after `click` this would do nothing. Anyway if you meant `jQuery('#myfield').click();` it is the same as `jQuery('#myfield').trigger('click');`

Comment: @jycr753, i m using version 1.8.2

Comment: @raina77ow, i'm trying to click on a select element

Comment: @JanL and t.niese, i also try  click() function, but it's not working too.

Comment: @ArnauddeVslt and what should happen if you trigger a `click` on a `<select>` element?